# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property System Entity

Tags: c#

So here is my call

```
Guid deliveryId = p.DeliveryDomainId;
string test = "TEST";
Guid realDeliveryID = Changepoint_Entities.P_BOOST_GENGetCodeDetailId(test, deliveryId);
```

And this is the method I try to call wich is an SQL procedure, the code is auto generated from a dmx file so I can't change this :

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<System.Guid>>P_BOOST_GENGetCodeDetailId(string codeType, Nullable<System.Guid> codeDetail)
{
    var codeTypeParameter = codeType != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("CodeType", codeType) :
        new ObjectParameter("CodeType", typeof(string));

    var codeDetailParameter = codeDetail.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("CodeDetail", codeDetail) :
        new ObjectParameter("CodeDetail", typeof(System.Guid));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<System.Guid>>("P_BOOST_GENGetCodeDetailId", codeTypeParameter, codeDetailParameter);
}
```

I get this error when compiling :

> Error 30  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'EBE.Entities.Changepoint_Entities.P_BOOST_GENGetCodeDetailId(string, System.Guid?)'  d:\userfiles\aorset\documents\gitrepo\dpaebe\ebe_final\ebe_final\controllers\datacontroller.cs  462 39  EBE_Final

I am a bit of a noobie in C# so I don't really what I am doing wrong. 
Do I need to use statics or something ? Because the call is in a for loop so I don't know what to do. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states, you need an instance of `Changepoint_Entities`:

```
Guid deliveryId = p.DeliveryDomainId;
string test = "TEST";
Changepoint_Entities changepoint = new Changepoint_Entities();
Guid realDeliveryID = changepoint.P_BOOST_GENGetCodeDetailId(test, deliveryId);
```

Comment: OMG I'm so dumb. Thx a lot I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

`P_BOOST_GENGetCodeDetailId()` is a non-static method but you ae calling like a static method and thus the error. You need to create a instance of `Changepoint_Entities` and call the method on that instance

```
Guid realDeliveryID = new Changepoint_Entities().P_BOOST_GENGetCodeDetailId(test, deliveryId);
```

(or) define the method as `static`

```
public static ObjectResult<Nullable<System.Guid>>P_BOOST_GENGetCodeDetailId(string codeType, Nullable<System.Guid> codeDetail)
{
```

Comment: Since "the code is auto generated from a dmx file so I can't change this :", the second option does not apply here

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, ahh!! missed that statement but anyways useful information ... right?

Comment: Of course, startic methods should be static :) shame on the auto-generated code